# jtable.org - icon location used to illustrate sample code

Tags: jquery-jtable

many of the code samples coming with jtable are presented with a both a phone and student list icons, referenced as phone.png and notes.png respectively.

Where are the icon files located? I would like to take advantage of the notes.png file as it is very generic to be used in some places of my code, thanks, Carlos

Comment: Here u can find them /Content/images/Misc/phone_metro.png

Comment: The icon was in front of my eyes all the time, I just forgot that clicking on it with the browser I was able do download it from the live example.